# XSLT: moving upfrom two for-each loops

Tags: xml, xslt

I know the basics of XSLT but I've got this really complicated document in XML from which I need to retrieve some elements. There is a for loop within a for loop and going upwards in the tree node.
I've done basic stuff but cannot get my head around the more difficult stuff.
I cannot post here the XML file I need to transform but here is a representation of my problem:

```
<Z xmlns="blablabla" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <A>
    <B>
        <C>date</C>
        <D>
           <F>client 1 data</F> 
           <E>
              <X>transaction 1</X>
           </E>
           <E>
              <X>transaction 2</X>
           </E>
        </D>
        <D>
        <F>client 2 data</F>  
           <E>
              <X>transaction 1</X>
           </E>
        </D>
     </B>
  </A>
</Z>
```

1. So there might be many  tags in  tag (one for each) and many  tags in  tag (so another for each). And when I'm inside  tag and retrieving data from there I need to use data from  tag which is outside of both of the loops. I need D * E sections and in every section I need to use the same data from tag  which is independent of data from  and .
2. And on top of all every tag is withing  and  and I'dont know how to use xsl:template match so I don't have to use  `<xsl:value-of select="z:A/z:B/z:C"/>` Is there a way to just define it once somewhere and then just use `<xsl:value-of select="z:C" />` ?

Here is my XSL file so far but unfortunately it's not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:z="blablabla">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="z:A/z:B">
          <xsl:value-of select="/z:C"/>
                  <xsl:for-each select="/z:D">
                         <xsl:for-each select="/z:E">
        should be repeated value from tag C in every section within those loops <xsl:value-of select="../../z:C"/>
                         </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output could be: (just to show you what I mean by sections)

```
date : client 1 data -> transaction 1, transaction 2
date : client 2 data -> transaction 1
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:z="blablabla">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="z:B">
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="z:C" />
    <xsl:for-each select="z:D">
        <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
        <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="z:F"/>
        <xsl:text> -> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="z:E">
            <xsl:value-of select="z:X"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can replace:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="z:E">
        <xsl:value-of select="z:X"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

with:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="z:E/z:X" separator=", "/>
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and check my EDIT 1? I can't get my real example to work woth your solution...

Comment: This seems to be a separate question. And the answer is that there are built-in template rules that process nodes for which you don't have a matching template. Either match the root element or add a template suppressing text.

Comment: But why it's working with your example? Why <xsl:template match="z:B"> doesn't output all the values in the B tag such as date from tag C? The structure is the same, isn't it?

Comment: Because the `Z` and `A` elements have no child text nodes.

Comment: I've created new question - if you coult help I would appreciate it because it's really hard for me to understand it - am no familiar with XSLT.
Link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099278/template-match-prints-everything-from-matching-tag